# Select element from dropdown list MDL HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, html-select, material-design-lite

I am newbie in web developer. I am coding select item after adding elements dynamically. I am using MDL (Google's Material Design Lite).
When I add elements by hand, it works perfectly,

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select getmdl-select__fix-height"  style="margin: 10px; width: 250px;">
  <input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="WC" readonly>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="WC">
  <label for="WC" class="mdl-textfield__label">WC</label>
  <ul for="WC" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu" id ="wc_list">
      <li class="mdl-menu__item" >1</li>
      <li class="mdl-menu__item" >2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But when I add elements by javascript, I cannot select any element.

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
   var li=document.createElement("li");
   li.className="mdl-menu__item";
   li.innerHTML="<li>"+i+"</li>";
   document.getElementById("wc_list").appendChild(li);
   componentHandler.upgradeElement(li);
}
```

How can I select element that added by javascript?

Comment: i dont see any actual html-select, you probably have to reinitialize after adding entries

Comment: I follow and use this class https://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/ without using html-select.

Comment: I find out that I put the code for loop in onreadystatechange event so that I cannot select any item while it work normally if the code is outside onreadystatechange. But have to use onreadystatechange event to update my data from server. Please help!!!

Comment: Were you able to solve this? When I create MDL li options for ul. The newly created li cannot be selected